# Prove $\liminf \left(\frac{n!}{(n-k)! n^k}\right) = 1,\ k =$ constant.

Tags: limits, probability-theory, permutations, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I had this as an assumption in my textbook (in the section **Poisson approximation to Binomial distribution**) but couldn't prove it.
[image: textbook - image for reference]

Comment: $n! /(n-k)! \geq (n-k+1)^k$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to prove that
$$\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{n^k}\to 1$$
as $n\to \infty$. Note that the product above has a finite number (k) of terms, and so when finding the limit of the above product, you may look at the product of the limits:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{\underbrace{n\cdot n\cdot ...\cdot n}_{k}}\\=\bigg(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n}\bigg)\bigg(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n-1}{n}\bigg)...\bigg(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n-k+1}{n}\bigg)$$
Each of these limits equals $1$, so the limit is $1$.